# Kernel panics too often OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I'm getting kernel panics more often than I'm comfortable with. I got one yesterday and one this week, not sure the exact frequency before that, but I got at least 4–5 of them within a day last week.

If anyone would care to look at the log it would be much appreciated.

I will keep posting logs here as they happen.

```
Anonymous UUID:       79CF750B-6274-B5EA-8453-7C4954FB16B0

Sat May  9 15:39:30 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8007617cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800730e241, 
type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff816e41e000, CR3: 0x00000001da19a0df, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x030404040f0d060f, RBX: 0xffffff80d8545400, RCX: 0xffffff80d854d4b0, RDX: 0x000000003f4d464f
RSP: 0xffffff8126e3bbc0, RBP: 0xffffff8126e3bc30, RSI: 0xffffff80d8545000, RDI: 0xffffff816e419a94
R8:  0xffffff816e41e000, R9:  0xffffff817185564c, R10: 0xffffff816e419ba0, R11: 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
R12: 0xfffffe9545e05000, R13: 0xffffff80d8545000, R14: 0xffffff802771a5a0, R15: 0x0000000016003d44
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff800730e241, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffff816e41e000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8126e3b870 : 0xffffff800752bda1 
0xffffff8126e3b8f0 : 0xffffff8007617cc2 
0xffffff8126e3bab0 : 0xffffff8007634b73 
0xffffff8126e3bad0 : 0xffffff800730e241 
0xffffff8126e3bc30 : 0xffffff800758f4e1 
0xffffff8126e3bca0 : 0xffffff800758dff5 
0xffffff8126e3bcd0 : 0xffffff8007590591 
0xffffff8126e3bd10 : 0xffffff80075996ff 
0xffffff8126e3bf20 : 0xffffff8007618224 
0xffffff8126e3bfb0 : 0xffffff8007634a85 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.WebKit
Boot args: vm_compressor=2

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 523763025766275
last loaded kext at 500235303558400: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f89e9c000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 500295329927424: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f89e9c000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.adguard.nfext   3
com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice 1.3
com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.4
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B08, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: My Passport 0820
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 6):

Here’s how I would troubleshoot this panic:

1. **You’ve disabled OSX’s native memory compression** using low level `sysctl` parameters: “`Boot args: vm_compressor=2`”. Clear that boot argument according to the command below, then test:

   `sudo nvram -d boot-args`
2. **Rule out third party software:** [The most common cause of kernel panics are third party kernel extensions which are either deprecated or incompatible with your OS X.](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/kernelpanics.html)

   - Boot up in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262), which loads only native drivers. If you cannot reproduce the panic (note - must be reproducible), then the culprit is most likely third party software. Likewise, if the panic still persists, then software isn’t the issue (and you can skip uninstallation instructions in the following paragraph).
   - Boot up normally and proceed to uninstall the software associated with these drivers ***according to the developer's instructions*** - in descending order as appearing in the panic report:

     - `com.adguard.nfext`
     - `com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice`
   - You can verify removal using a simple Terminal command. There should be no output: `kextstat | grep -v apple`
3. **[Without third party drivers, a kernel panic can only be caused by a few things:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553)**

   - **A peripheral device:** Disconnect any external drives, I/O devices, hubs, etc, to rule this out.
   - **A bad OSX image** or bug in OS X itself: [Reinstall OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18872?locale=en_US) to rule out a bad image.
   - **A hardware problem**: In terms of hardware, faulty RAM modules are often to blame. A repeated error code of `type 14` (a page fault) is an indication of such. [Run the Apple Hardware test (or Apple Diagnostics)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) and see if an error code is produced. Both the RAM modules and certain logic board components are tested, but it’s still notoriously a test prone to false negatives.
   - If you get to this point, I suggest bringing your machine into Apple and have them run in house diagnostics for a definitive diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

I read following as possible trouble makers:

- globaldelight app

  Uninstall the Boom app and test kernel panics without it.
- AdGuard App

  Remove it and test without it.

To take a closer look at what processes died in the last 7 days use this Terminal command:

```
ps aux | grep -w Z
```

It will show you the list of processes that died.

Answer (score 1):

I am 98% certain it is a bug in OS X Yosemite, introduced with the 10.10.3 update. Welcome [aboard](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7000724). The kernel panics are totally erratic, some users have also graphics glitches. The only common feature is having a Intel HD 4000 GPU.

On MacBook Pros with dual GPU you can avoid the problem by **disabling Automatic Graphics Switching** (System Preferences > Energy Saver).

After countless phone calls with Apple, I will take my Mac to the Apple Store tomorrow. I am sure they won't find a thing. Then they will keep my Mac for five days, replace the logic board and the issue will persist. Please proof me wrong Apple...

Please contribute to the [thread in the apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7000724) and file a bug report (with link to the thread).