# Is there an (automated) test suite to find bugs for OSX?

Tags: macos, bug, kernel-panic

Apple introduced a [nasty issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7000724) with OSX 10.10.3 (see also questions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/186449) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/197700)). Some Macs with an Intel HD 4000 have random kernel panics and sometimes graphics glitches.

However, the problem is practically not reproducible. It often happens when people do everyday things like web browsing. Also it occurs randomly. Sometimes several times a day and sometimes once a month. Therefore it is hard to convince Apple of this bug.

Do you know of any automated test suite that will test or simulate different use patterns in OS X? My hope is that this might help me narrow the issue down a little.

Comment: Does this issue persist with OS X Yosemite 10.10.4?

Comment: @user3439894 yes. apparently also in 10.10.5 beta. 10.11 seems to be free of the issue so far.

Comment: That would imply would be pointless filing bug reports if they know it's a bug & have already fixed it down the line; you'll just be closed as a dupe.

Comment: Usually Apple maintains the last 2-3 OSX major releases. Maybe this has changed with the annual release cycle... I still hope they fix it because migrating is always painful and the first release versions are basically still beta.

Answer (score 1):

Being a few years wiser now, I would today probably use [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com) to narrow the issue down.